# Javascript from shell script

Tags: javascript, bash, shell, cgi

Is it possible to call javascript inside a shell script? 
For example,

```
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo "
     <html>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     document.write("<p>" + Date() + "</p>");
     </script>
     </html>
     "
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you could? This could be answered in so many different ways depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script is used by [CGI (Common Gateway Interface)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) application, then yes, you can include HTML with embedded JavaScript.

EDIT: JavaScript is a client-side technology. You won't get any trace of JavaScript running on server, because it won't be executed on server (unless we're talking about Server Side JavaScript but I don't think so).

Comment: @thetux: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve - see my comment.

Answer (score 3):

By default: No. But you could install applications that can run javascript like node.js or rhino.

Comment: It's also possible to start a node.js script from a shell script using the command `node name_of_script.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Try [RhinoShell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_Shell).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install a *javascript engine* on your system to be able to call it from **bash** and execute your javascript code. Check [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey).

Comment: After searching our forums a little, I found out that your question might be too related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2283234/176769